# google cloud vpc bind external network ip,but show red error notice,unable to delete and modify

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

The vm deleted, but the error of external network ip still exists. Unable to delete and modify. Check below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error occurs after you release the External IP address, and it keeps for a while under the GUI, but you can confirm by gcloud command is the VM still there:

Example: gcloud compute instances delete  --zone

Also, you can check by gcloud command what instances are in your project:

gcloud compute instances list

gcloud commands are faster that GUI, do you still see the error?